# Android widget to input duration

Tags: android, time, duration

Which android widget will be appropriate to get a duration time (hours and minutes) defined by a user? I think about a TimePicker, but it looks that it was created to get a time of a day.

Are there any other standard possibility, or I should write it from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `TimePicker` by `customizing` the time that you give to the `TimePickerDialog`.

The idea is to get the input defines by the user, format it and pass it to `TimePickerDialog`